# Send login and password to mail in symfony 2

Tags: php

How can I send login and password to email in symfony 2?
I need that after registering an account, a login and password are sent to the mail that the user specified!
I can’t implement, for some reason
Thanks in advance :)!
Here is the code:

```
class RegController extends Controller
{
    private $eventDispatcher;
    private $formFactory;
    private $userManager;
    private $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher, FactoryInterface $formFactory, UserManagerInterface $userManager, TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->eventDispatcher = $eventDispatcher;
        $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
        $this->userManager = $userManager;
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }
    public function registerAction(Request $request)
    {

        $user = $this->userManager->createUser();
        $user->setEnabled(true);

        $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
        $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE, $event);

        if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
            return $event->getResponse();
        }

        $form = $this->createForm(RegistrationType::class, $user);
        $form->setData($user);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
                $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS, $event);

                $this->userManager->updateUser($user);

                if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
                    $url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_registration_confirmed');
                    $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
                }

                $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));
                return $response;

            }

            $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
            $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_FAILURE, $event);

            if (null !== $response = $event->getResponse()) {
                return $response;

            }


        return $this->render('@FOSUser/Registration/register.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }


}
```

How to do it right? Help please!

Comment: Where is your code to send email

Comment: It is not there, I deleted it, because it did not work! I can find it again if necessary!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send email containing login and pass after registration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17742030/send-email-containing-login-and-pass-after-registration)

Comment: @Shibon No, I tried, it did not work !!!

Comment: Are you using any bundle for user registration, else try FOSUserbundle or else add the code which you used to send mail

Comment: @Shibon So where to add the code to the controller? Can you please write !?